# or-tools Employee Scheduling sequential allocations staff groups

Tags: optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

Using standard/simple nursing example:
https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling

I'm trying to enforce nurses from a particular group/team to be allocated days consecutively.
As below, nurses 1-9 split into "groups". If nurse 9 is allocated first, then other members from group (4 and 7) should be allocated to following days.

Thinking I can possibly achieve this by counting the amount of times members from a group are allocated one day after another, but am unable to count when this occurs, i.e. both day_i and day_i+1 are allocated to nurses from same group.

```py
groups = [[3,7,8],[1,6],[5],[4,9,7]] #nurses 3,7,8 are in same group
...
for g in groups:
    for d1, d2 in zip(all_days[:-1],all_days[1:]):
        d1_alloc = sum(shifts[(n, d1, s)] for n in g)
        d2_alloc = sum(shifts[(n, d2, s)] for n in g)
        # ??? how to say only count when both sums = 1/true ???
        # for a group of 3, i.e. [3,7,8] this should occur twice within period
```

Full Code:

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

all_days = range(1,10)
all_nurses = range(1,10)
groups = [[3,7,8],[1,6],[5],[4,9,7]] #nurses 3,7,8 are in same group
s=1 #1 shift only

model = cp_model.CpModel()

shifts = {}
for d in all_days:
    for n in all_nurses:
        shifts[(n, d, s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%sd%is%i' % (n, d, s))
            
# one nurse per shift
for d in all_days:
    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)
               
# everyone works a shift
for n in all_nurses:
    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for d in all_days) == 1)
 
# nurses within group should be allocated days one after another
# order of groups is not important - last group [4,9,7] could be allocated firts
# order within groups is not important - can be 7,4,9
    
for g in groups:
    for d1, d2 in zip(all_days[:-1],all_days[1:]):
        d1_alloc = sum(shifts[(n, d1, s)] for n in g)
        d2_alloc = sum(shifts[(n, d2, s)] for n in g)
        # ??? how to say only count when both sums 1/true ???
        # for a group of 3, i.e. [3,7,8] this should occur twice within period


solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)

for d in all_days:
    for n in all_nurses:
        if solver.Value(shifts[(n, d, s)]) == 1:
            print('Day: '+str(d)+' = Nurse '+str(n))
```

EDIT:
The following logic can be used to achieve this

```py
for group in groups:     
    for n1, n2 in zip(group[:-1],group[1:]):
        for d in all_days[:-1]:

            model.AddBoolOr([shifts[n1, d, 1],shifts[n2, d+1, 1].Not()])
            model.AddBoolOr([shifts[n1, d, 1].Not(),shifts[n2, d+1, 1]])
```

This solution is restrictive - Allocations must follow the same sequence as the group is listed. Group [3,7,8] will always be 3,7,8 but not 7,3,8 or 8,3,7 for example... which would also be fine.

It is also necessary to ensure that Day 1 is allocated to someone from the start of a group.
model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, 1, s)] for n in [3,1,5,4]) ==1)

If there are only groups of up to 2 members, the following will allow either order. For group [3,7] for example... 3,7 or 7,3.

```py
for group in groups:     
    for n1, n2 in zip(group[:-1],group[1:]):
        
        #Day1
        model.AddImplication(shifts[n1, 1, 1],shifts[n2, 2, 1])
        model.AddImplication(shifts[n2, 1, 1],shifts[n1, 2, 1])
        
        #Day2 + must check preceding day to avoid circular/repeated allocations
        for d in all_days[1:-1]:
            
          model.AddImplication(shifts[n1, d, 1],shifts[n2, d+1, 1]).OnlyEnforceIf(shifts[n2, d-1, 1].Not())
          model.AddImplication(shifts[n2, d, 1],shifts[n1, d+1, 1]).OnlyEnforceIf(shifts[n1, d-1, 1].Not())
```

EDIT 2:
The following can be used to solve for groups of any size...

```py
for g in groups:
    
    for i in range(0,len(g)):
        #1 cycle for every group order [3,7,2], [7,2,3],[2,3,7]

        for d in all_days[:-(len(g)-1)]:
            
            conditions_met = [shifts[g[0], d, 1]] #n1 allocated today
            if d > 1:
                #ensure group members not allocated previous day
                for n in g:
                    conditions_met.append(shifts[n, d-1, 1].Not())
            
            #apply rules for next x days - depending on size of group
            for day in range(d+1,d+len(g)):
                or_cond = []
                for n in g[1:]:
                    or_cond.append(shifts[n,day,1])
                model.AddBoolOr(or_cond).OnlyEnforceIf(conditions_met)

        x = g.pop(0)
        g.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex constraints, I suggest looking at [this shift scheduling example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py)

In particular in contains min and max sequence constraints.

Comment: Thanks Laurent. I did see this example but thought there might be a simpler way to achieve this. Could you tell me please if something like either of the following is possible to do:

-IF d1_alloc is TRUE then... 
-Max(0,(d1_alloc + d2_alloc - 1))  #assuming only 1 would be returned if both d1,d2 are true

I will take some time to go through the example provided and see if I can reproduce. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Laurent. I was able to solve my problem using similar logic to that of the example you provided. (See code edit above). The solution is a bit restrictive however, the sequence of a group must remain ordered. For group [3,7,8], if nurse 3 works then nurse 7 will work the following day, and nurse 8 the next. In reality, this order does not need to be followed - 7,3,8 for example would also be fine. Can you recommend an approach to make this solution more flexible?

Comment: Use implications(work[7][day] => work[3][day + 1]) for all day in days

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Laurent. I tested and implications work well if groups only have up to 2 members, see edit above. Take [3,7] for example...
If day 1 = 3 then day 2 = 7 or vice versa. The OnlyEnforceIf is used to stop a repetitive cycle (3,7,3,7...)

But if there is 3 in a group [3,7,8], I would have to say something like: 7 implies 3 or 8 but only 3 if not previously allocated, and only 8 if not previously allocated.
Similarly, 3 => 8 or 7... 8 => 3 or 7

The larger the group the more permutations that need to be covered. Do you think there is a better alternative?

Comment: worker[3][day] -> or(option_a, option_b). then option_a (temp var) => work[7][day + 1] and optiona_b => work[8][day + 1], and same thing for day + 2. Does it solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply again Laurent. I think this might work but I am a little unsure of how to code. Is it something like this..

a = model.NewBoolVar('a')
b = model.NewBoolVar('b')

model.AddImplication(shifts[n1, d, 1],model.AddBoolOr(a,b))
model.AddImplication(a,shifts[n2, d+1, 1])
model.AddImplication(b,shifts[n3, d+1, 1])

Comment: `s => a or b` is equivalent to `not s or a or b`. Thus `model.AddBoolOr([s.Not(), a, b])`. You can also write `model.AddBoolOr([a, b]).OnlyEnforceIf(s)`

Comment: Laurent, many thanks for your help. I was able to solve (as per EDIT 2 above). It seems I was over complicating the problem when saying "7 implies 3 or 8 BUT ONLY 3 if not previously allocated..". All I need to say is 7 implies 3 or 8. I can make sure 3 or 8 is not repeated with a different rule. My solution currently applies rules for different group permutations... 7 (on day1) => 3 or 8 (on day2)/ 8 => 3 or 7 / 3 => 7 or 8 - model.AddBoolOr(7,8).OnlyEnforceIf(8). It could simplified to be 3 or 7 or 8 => 3 or 7 or 8. Is something like AddBoolOr(3,7,8).OnlyEnforceIf(OR(3,7,8)) possible?